# NSDateFormatter seems to have the wrong month

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter, iso8601

I have this block of code to read in the ISO 8601 Date/Time specification. The problem is that for some reason, the month doesn't work. Every time I convert it month is "01". What am I doing wrong?

```
NSDateFormatter *UTCDateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[UTCDateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
[UTCDateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[UTCDateFormat setCalendar:[[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease]];
[UTCDateFormat setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];
NSLog(@"%@", [UTCDateFormat dateFromString:dateString]);
```

So, for example, if dateString was:

```
@"2002-03-12T21:13:27Z"
```

my output would be:

```
2002-01-12 21:13:27 +0000
```

Things I have already tried:

- Changed MM to LL
- Tried without setCalendar/setLocale
- tried with ' around the -
- switched position of MM around to other places. It never changes anything.
- Looked all over SO and it appears to work for everyone else.

Comment: This may not change anything, but I think `DD` format specifier should be `dd`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this

```
    [UTCDateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
```

DD is the "Day of the year" not the "Day of a month". A great source for looking up NSDateFormatter formats is [this table](http://waracle.net/mobile/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/)

Comment: wow... So why in the world was the DD preventing MM from working? Doesn't seem like that should happen. But thanks a lot!

Comment: 'this table' is amazing! That should be the Apple documentation.